# Python OpenCV - customizing mask

Tags: python, opencv

I am having a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRD0.jpg) here. The region within the yellow lines is my region of interest, as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuuUO.jpg) here, which is also one of my objective. Here's my planning / steps:

1. Denoise, color filtering, masking and Canny edging (DONE)
2. Coordinates of the edges (DONE)
3. Select coordinates of certain vertices, for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkX0Y.jpg)
4. Draw polygon with those vertices' coordinates

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

frame = cv2.imread('realtest.jpg')

denoisedFrame = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(frame, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)

HSVframe = cv2.cvtColor(denoisedFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 

lower_yellowColor = np.array([15,105,105]) 
upper_yellowColor = np.array([25,255,255])

whiteMask = cv2.inRange(HSVframe, lower_yellowColor, upper_yellowColor) 
maskedFrame = cv2.bitwise_and(denoisedFrame, denoisedFrame, mask=whiteMask)

grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(maskedFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gaussBlurFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayFrame, (5,5), 0)
edgedFrame = cv2.Canny(grayFrame, 100, 200)

#Coordinates of each white pixels that make up the edges
ans = []

for y in range(0, edgedFrame.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0, edgedFrame.shape[1]):
        if edgedFrame[y, x] != 0:
            ans = ans + [[x, y]]

ans = np.array(ans)

#print(ans.shape)
#print(ans[0:100, :])


cv2.imshow("edged", edgedFrame)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see, I have successfully done step number (2) in getting the coordinates of each white pixels that make the edges. Whereas for the next step, step number (3), I am stuck. I have tried the coding [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/), but getting error that says 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'.

Please help teaching me in finding good vertices for constructing a polygon that is as close to the yellow lines as possible.

Comment: Mask yellow area, find contours of outer bound of yellow area with enough points. if you have too many values to pack, you can say for example instead of `a = cv2.funcX()` this: `a,_ = cv2.funcX()`. This is typical problem, if you use BW/GREYSCALE/COLOR images together (their numpy-arrays have different dimensions).

Comment: But I can't just throw away the returns by using _, right? Because they may be important vertices?

Answer (score 1):

I have split the answer into two parts

**Part 1**: ***Finding the good vertices to construct a polygon***

The required vertices around an image containing edges can be done using OpenCV's inbuilt `cv2.findContours()` function. It returns the image with contours, vertices of the contours and the hierarchy of the contours.

One can find vertices of contours in two ways:

- `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` plots **ALL** the coordinates(boundary points) on each contour
- `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` plots **ONLY** the most necessary coordinates on each contour. It doesn't store all the points. Only the most required coordinates that best represent the contours are stored.

In your case option 2 can be opted. After finding the edges you can do the following:

```
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(edgedFrame, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

`contours` contains the vertices of every contour in the image `edgedFrame`

**Part 2**: ***Constructing the polygon***

Opencv has an in-built function for this as well `cv2.convexHull()` After finding those points you can draw them using `cv2.drawContours()`.

```
for cnt in contours:
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [hull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Polygon", frame)
```

[image]

You can obtain a better approximation of the desired edge by doing some more pre-processing while creating the mask

Comment: thanks so much for the crystal clear explanation. Based on the photo you posted, is it possible to remove the smaller rectangle (the inner rectangle)? What method / approach I need to use?

Comment: @stacknoflow Yes! After finding the edges in the image `edgedFrame `, perform some morphological operation (erosion/dilation) such that when you find the contours only the external frame is detected.